# selinux context_new return value

Tags: linux, selinux

According to [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/context_new), "On success, zero is returned" but none of the functions mentioned return 0. They are all returning `const char *` or void. Can someone please clarify in which case 0 will be returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After asking this question on selinux official mailing list, it is a bug and they will fix it. context_new actually assigns memory block